# Is $\frac{ \Delta \ \text{endogenous variable}_1 }{\Delta \ \text{endogenous variable}_2}$ well-defined ... and what is it?

Tags: macroeconomics

When solving economic models, wec get expressions of endogenous variables (say, production $P$, or consumption $C$) in terms of parameters or exogenous variales, and we can then ask what the change in, say, production is given a change in, say, public spending.

But can we also ask what the change in production is given a change in another endogenous variable, like for example $C$? That is, what is $$\frac{\Delta P}{\Delta C},$$ for example in the simple goods market model where the equations are $$\text{Demand} = C + \text{investments} + \text{public spending}, \\ C = c_0 + c_1(P - \text{taxes}), \\ P = \text{Demand},$$ where $P, \text{Demand}$ and $C$ are endogenous?

I have searched online and found that the answer is infinity, but no explanation is given. Why is it infinity?

Comment: can you provide references for your online search?